# In CRM 2011, how can I find more information on why an entity failed to be created?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am currently mapping data in Scribe from a system to CRM 2011, and I receive an error from CRM that it cannot create the entity I need.

```
   Error Number:  0x00000380 (896)
   Native Error:  0x00000000 (0)
   Source:        System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX]]: Invalid Recurrence Pattern
   Description:   Invalid Recurrence Pattern
```

This is all the information CRM will give me however. Is there a way in CRM to get more explicit details about why an attempt to create an entity failed? Specifically, what field data was found to be invalid, or what required field may be missing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daryl! The entity is Recurring Appointment (recurringappointmentmaster).

Comment: @Andy it looks pretty explicit, your translation in Scribe is faulty.  Create the exact pattern in CRM and compare it to the pattern you're trying to make in Scribe.  I bet you'll discover that CRM was telling you the pattern is invalid.